# Why am I getting this error when i use strcat in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
    int a;
    double b;
    char c[60];
    scanf("%d %lf", &a, &b);
    scanf("%[^\n]", c);
    char r[100];
    strcpy(r, s);
    strcat(r, c);
    a += i;
    b += d;
    printf("%d\n%.1lf\n%s", a, b, r);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output i get for this code is

```
16
8.0
HackerRank �j�&�
```

And the expected output is

```
16
8.0
HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

Can someone help me out with the error regarding the strcat part?

Comment: or newline at the end of first scanf format, `scanf("%d %lf\n",&a,&b);`

Comment: @Dialecticus in the general case xing's solution is to be preferred: strip leading whitespace not trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks a ton @xing. It worked. Can you explain why it worked now but not before?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d %lf", &a, &b);1 and `scanf("%[^\n]", c);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant Undefined Behavior